# How can I fix this code in a built-in Simulink Matlab Function?

Tags: function, matlab

I am having some problems with my Matlab code. The code works perfectly fine on MatLab, but when i try and introduce it in a MatLab Function in Simulink, it does not seem to function anymore.

Here is my code :

```
First_Value = false; % Initialize the variable

for i = 1:1016 % This is an I counter that counts through all of Fault_Data's arrays
    % If loop number 1 ( Sensor Stepwise )
    if Fault_Data(i, 2) == 1 && Fault_Data(700,2)==1 % Check if the value is equal to 1 and STAYS 1
        disp(['Sensor Stepwise error  at Step ', num2str(i), ' Equivalent to T = 20 seconds']);
        First_Value = true; % Set variable to true to indicate that a value of 1 has been found and that it doesn't repeat again
        break; % Exit the loop as soon as the value is found

    end 
    % If Loop number 2 ( Actuator Stepwise ) % Need to modify this because
    % there is a problem with these conditions

    if(Fault_Data(i,2) > 0 && Actuator_Data(i,2)==0.563667687001417 && Actuator_Data(i,2)<= 0.57 ) % Perhaps just use values and not gradients ? As soon as the fault data isn't 0, detect an Error
    disp(['Actuator Stepwise error  at Step ', num2str(i), ' Equivalent to T = ' ]);
    First_Value=true;
    disp ( Fault_Data(616,2)/Fault_Data(955,2));
    break;
    end

% If Loop number 3 (Sensor Driftwise)
  if (Fault_Data(i,2) > 0 && ( Sensor_Data(1016,2) > 0.1 && Sensor_Data(1016,2)<=0.2)) % Final Value of Driftwise Error is correct
    disp(['Sensor Driftwise error  at Step ', num2str(i) ]);
    First_Value=true;
    break;
  end 

% If Loop number 4 (Actuator Driftwise)
 if (Fault_Data(i,2) ~= 0 && Actuator_Data(815,2)>=2 && Sensor_Data(800,2)>=267 && Sensor_Data(800,2)<=267.5) % Perhaps just use values and not gradients ? As soon as the fault data isn't 0, detect an Error
    disp(['Actuator Driftwise error  at Step ', num2str(i) ]);
    disp (Actuator_Data(i,2))
    First_Value=true;
    break;
 end 
% If Loop number 5 ( Actuator Stepwise and Sensor Stepwise )

 if (Fault_Data(i,2) ~= 0 && Actuator_Data(212,2)>= 0.5 && Sensor_Data(212,2)>=1) % Perhaps just use values and not gradients ? As soon as the fault data isn't 0, detect an Error
    disp(['Start of Faults at Step  ', num2str(i), ', Actuator and Sensor Stepwise Fault' ]);
    disp (Actuator_Data(i,2))
    First_Value=true;
    break;
 end 
% If Loop number 6 ( Actuator Driftwise and Sensor Driftwise )
if (Fault_Data(i,2) ~= 0 && Actuator_Data(1016,2)>= 3 && Sensor_Data(1016,2)>=1000) % Perhaps just use values and not gradients ? As soon as the fault data isn't 0, detect an Error
    disp(['Start of Faults at Step  ', num2str(i), ', Actuator and Sensor Driftwise Fault' ]);
    disp (Actuator_Data(i,2))
    First_Value=true;
    break;
end
   
end
    
OUTPUT = u;
```

The errors I am getting are :

- Simulink cannot determine sizes and/or types of the outputs for block 'detectionforboth/MATLAB Function2' due to errors in the block body, or limitations of the underlying analysis. The errors might be inaccurate. Fix the indicated errors, or explicitly specify sizes and/or types for all block outputs.
- Error in port widths or dimensions. 'Output Port 1' of 'detectionforboth/MATLAB Function2/Fault_Data' is a one dimensional vector with 1 elements.
  Component:Simulink | Category:Model error
- Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 700. The valid range is 1-1.

What's expected is that the code reads the appropriate values with the right indexes, but it doesn't seem to work